# Labview call subVI as independent window

Tags: labview

VI A is my primary user interface. At the click of a button, it may open a separate window, VI B, which may remain open for an extended period of time and operate independently of A. Now, my question is, what is the best practice for how to call B, without hanging the user interface of A? The software will be built into an app, so I can't use anything involving VI Server.

Comment: I'd look at the [Event Structure Producer-Consumer pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0NxAmx6b90) to handle user commands from the front panels of A and B, and [Channel Wires](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvconcepts/channel_wires_intro/) to pass data between them if that's a requirement.

Comment: Thanks, Joe, but with all due respect, that video has nothing to do with having multiple VI's independently interacting with the user.

Comment: You can use VI Server for executable application. There are some properties/invoke nodes which are not accessible at run-time, but most of them could be used at run-time.

Comment: The video has a few things related to handling user input from multiple front panels, but if you're new to the [Event structure](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/event_structure/), I can see why you'd miss them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the scale of your project.

The smallest scale solution is to just call it as a subVI in parallel to the rest of your code. You have a while loop around an event structure for your main window... have a second while loop with an event structure running in parallel. The second loop only monitors for the one event that launches your subVI. If you need the subVI to communicate with the rest of your app, pass into it a channel wire, or queue refnums, or user event refnums.

At larger scale apps, you’ll want a messaging framework of some sort. The one that ships with LabVIEW is Actor Framework. There’s shipping help to learn how to use it (create a new project and look at the template projects). Other messaging frameworks exist from third parties with various levels of sophistication and feature richness.

Comment: Really? In the past we were told NEVER to have two event structures in the same VI, they would simply fight each other for events – a behavior that I observed, about eight years ago.

Comment: It is fine to have two as long as they are tracking separate events. @joymaker It’s actually fine to have them track the same events, and that’s commonly done for user events, but for built-in events, the behavior is well-defined but so counterintuitive that it isn’t something most people should attempt.